# Tokenizing, separating tokens split by punctuation

Tags: python, list, nltk, tokenize

Given a text like "Great drinks , beef hash, coffee, burritos.", I know I can tokenize it with NLTK's Tweet Tokenizer for example to produce:

```
['Great',
 'drinks',
 ',',
 'beef',
 'hash',
 ',',
 'coffee',
 ',',
 'burritos',
 '.']
```

I would like to treat each part preceding a comma and full stop separately to produce a list like `[Great drinks, beef hash, coffee, burritos]`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s= "Great drinks , beef hash, coffee, burritos."
print (re.findall(r"[\w']+", s))
```

For words with '-'(hyphen)

```
print (re.findall(r"([\w']+(?:\S-\S)?[\w'])+", s))
```

Comment: perfect - thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = "Great drinks , beef hash, coffee, burritos."
msg.translate(str.maketrans(",.", "  ")).split()
```

does the job.

Comment: If the punctuation character increases,its too lengthy